# How to minify my google chrome extension's javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am finished up with my google chrome extension development. Now its time to deploy on google chrome extension dashboard. But the problem is How do I **minify** my javascript files (background.js and content.js). I can use online tools available but they do one file at a time and do not consider the dependency on other javascript file.

For example, message passing between background.js and content.js is done by a key value, which tells the other party that what kind of message is this.
I am not sure whether chrome itself minifies my javascript file. I little illiterate here. Please help.

Comment: This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522315/minify-an-entire-directory-while-keeping-element-style-script-relationships

Comment: Why would you minify Chrome extension files? It's extra work for virtually no gain.

Comment: To obfuscate my code to some extent. Since my code is very well formatted PLUS it calls a web API service which is quiet open, which I feel a spoiler can do it even if i minify my code. :( ...any suggestion how do i secure my web api which is being used for google chrome extension

Comment: It's official. [Chrome Web Store will no longer allow extensions with obfuscated code.](https://blog.chromium.org/2018/10/trustworthy-chrome-extensions-by-default.html#:~:text=Starting%20today%2C%20Chrome%20Web%20Store%20will%20no%20longer%20allow%20extensions%20with%20obfuscated%20code.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chrome doesn't perform any minification out of the box. Your Chrome extension will load the JavaScript/CSS files as is - minification is completely up to you. Most extensions are left unminified for ease of debugging and for other users to be able to inspect the code. There should be negligible performance gains typically for extensions.

If you do want to **minify** you can run uglify tasks using [grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) or [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify).

Answer (score 0):

To minify HTML, try [HTMLMinifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier)
To minify CSS, try [CSSNano](https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano) and [csso](https://github.com/css/csso).
To minify JavaScript, try [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2). The [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler) is also [very effective](https://github.com/samccone/The-cost-of-transpiling-es2015-in-2016#summary-of-findings). You can create a build process that uses these tools to minify and rename the development files and save them to a production directory.

Ref: [Minify Resources (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript)](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources)